# How to count the tru/false values in a json array?

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I am making a small project in AS3 (FlashDevelop) to catch a JSON file which contains the following:

```
"properties" : [ 
    {
        "statement1" : true
    }, 
    {
        "statement2" : true
    }, 
    {
        "statement3" : true
    }, 
    {
        "statement4" : false
    }, 
    {
        "statement5" : true
    }, 
    {
        "statement6" : false
    }
],
```

Within my AS3 code I am monitoring it like this:

```
if (this.sessionController.currentSession.visitor.properties.statement4 == true) {
            _counterStatements=+1;
        }
        else {
            _counterStatements=-1;
        }
```

Is there an more easy/shorter way to do this? It seems like I am just outputting useless code now.

Many thanks in advance.

Greetings,

Bram

ps. I want to count the true/false arguments

Comment: Is it right that your `properties` array in JSON contains elements that have a random name ("statementX" or maybe "blablabla") and a value of true or false? And is it right that each array element has a single property?

Comment: Yeah it is, the full JSON looks like this:

    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("92319SDGA"),
    "token" : "TRESTSET",
    "name" : "Peter",
    "email" : null,
    "language" : "EN",
    "external_id" : null,
    "properties" : [ 
        {
            "statement1" : true
        }, 
        {
            "statement2" : true
        }, 
        {
            "statement3" : true
        }, 
        {
            "statement4" : false
        }, 
        {
            "statement5" : true
        }, 
        {
            "statement6" : false
        }
    ]

}

Comment: This structure is not very good, just use an array in json and put the boolean values in it. There's no point in wrapping each value into its own object with a single property. Can you change the json structure?

Comment: Yes I can, its a series of questions you need to awnser with true/false. Open for suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var properties:Array=this.sessionController.currentSession.visitor.properties; // copy-pasted
var sum:int=0;
for each (var ob:Object in properties) {
    for (var s:String in ob) { if (ob[s]===true) sum++; else if (ob[s]===false) sum--; }
}
```

Or alternatively you can use `for each` loop to just ignore property names:

```
for each (var p:* in ob) { if (p===true) sum++; else if (p===false) sum--; }
```

Here, you don't care of what's the property name is, although you can still filter by condition on `s` within the inner loop, but you care about values, and triple equality means the type of that value should be equal, say `0==false` is true, but `0===false` is false.

Comment: Thnx for the awesome reply! Trying to get it to work but my logging of "sum" keeps returning "0" :(

Comment: Please investigate if `properties` is actually populated with an array, and if `ob` is actually an object. You can always iterate through an array the normal way.

Comment: I cant seem to get past the "for (var s:String in ob)" part

Comment: It worked! Seemed like our API had some buggy thing that made all objects into strings, and by doing so not recognizing the objects :) thank you for your help!

Comment: Cant set your awnser to awnsered though :( need 15 rep

Comment: Upvoting requires 15 rep (an up arrow), marking as accepted is done by clicking a "tick" under the answer's rating.